# A reference to two variables will change two variables's address into the same?

Tags: c++, reference

I find a very interesting thing and that breaks my consistent idea.

```
    int a = 1;
    int a1 = 11;
    int &b = a;
    b = a1;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << a1 << endl;
```

What I thought is that `b` refs to `a`'s address, and `b = a1` just changes `b` ref into `a1`'s address.
But the output of `a` turns out `b = a1` changes `a`'s address as well, and both refs to `a1`.

So is it some kind of trap of using reference? What I mean when using `b = a1` is just changing the reference of `b` into `a1` instead of `a`(similar using of pointers), but never want any relations still remains between `a` and `b`.

Comment: You can't reassign a reference. Once initialized to reference a specific variable it will always reference that variable. So `b = a1` is the same as `a = a1`. Think of references as a kind of alias instead, `b` will always be an alias for `a` in your case.

Comment: Pointers are like symlinks, references like hardlinks if that helps. Or think of `a` itself as just a name which *refers* the underlying `int` object. `b` then is just another name for the same `int` object. Although either analogy is not 100% true since the lifetime is governed by `a` only, not by `b`.

Comment: *'b = a1 just changes b ref into a1's address'* No, it assigns the value to `a1` to `a` (i.e. what `b` is referring to). References are not like pointers, you **cannot** make them refer to something else.

Comment: "Changes a's address as well". No, that can't happen. You are making the mistake of only printing the values. Try printing the addresses (`cout << &b << endl` etc). You will see that a and b have the same address while a1 has a different one. The *values* are the same after your assignment, though, as to be expected.

Comment: I think you're overthinking it by involving addresses. After `int &b = a;`, the names "a" and "b" refer to the same `int`. (If you give your uncle Robert the nickname "Bob", then it is the same person regardless of what you call him.)

Comment: `b = a1`  doesn't "reseat" the reference `b` so it refers to `a1`.    It assigns the variable that `b` refers to so it has the same value as `a1`.    Since `b` is defined/initialised as `int &b = a`, the assignment `b = a1` has the same effect as `a = a1`.   Which causes neither the names `a` nor `b` to refer to the variable `a1`.

Answer (score 1):

From a beginner's perspective, `int &b = a;` is almost the same as `int* const p = &a;` The only difference is that references are used in the same way as instances.

To exaggerate a little, `b = a1;` is almost the same as `*p = a1;` and it means `a = a1;` Just think of a reference as a pointer that is always dereferenced with `*`.